# Windows 10 : your pc couldnt start properly

Tags: windows-10

When I start Windows 10 i received the message: "

"Your PC couldn't start properly.

A required device isnt connected or cant be accessed.
Error code: 0xc0000225

You'll need to use recovery tools.  If you don't have any install media (like a disc or USB device), contact your PC administrator or PC/device manufacturer."

I believe this started due to the machine not shutdown correctly.  I can start in safe mode and no recovery points are disabled.

Any ideas on how i can get this machine back?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

- Press and hold F2 key(depend on your PC), then power on the machine. You will be directed to BIOS.
- Look for Security tab inside bios and navigate to Secure Boot. Then Disable it.

[image]

- Now go to Advanced → System Configuration
  Hit Enter key in System Configuration

[image]

- Change Boot Mode in to CSM Mode.

[image]

- Whenever you change Boot Mode from EUFI to CSM mode, another option will come just above the boot mode, SATA Controller Mode. Hit Enter key in SATA Controller Mode and make it Compatibility mode.

[image]

- Save settings and Exit by hitting F10 key…

That’s all, you are able to boot from DVD drive, and obliviously you can repair your Windows 8 PC with disk.

**Taken Source :**

http://www.smartpctricks.com/2013/09/solved-error-code-0xc000000f-windows-8-a-required-device-isnt-connected-or-cant-be-accessed.html

Comment: Thanks for posting so quick.  Its intel compute stick so i don't have all the options.  Are you saying the i need to repair or re-install windows 10 completely? 
http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/compute-stick/intel-compute-stick.html